# url encode %09 not working in email

Tags: unicode, html-email

Not sure why but the unicode for the tab key %09 isn't working when I put it in my a tag. The space and linefeed are both working just not the tab. It seems to be converting it to a space. Maybe it was colapsing the whitespace so I put a ~ in front of one of the tabs.

here is my a tag

```
<a href="mailto:yes@mydomain.com?subject=My%20Application&body=Please%20include%20the%20following:%0A%0Ayour%20name%0Acontact%20information%20%0A%09phone:%20%0A~%09email:%20%0A%09and%20address:%0A%0AThank%20You">click here</a>
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the URL itself and everything to do with the client's `mailto` handler that acts on the url. There is no guarantee that tabs are preserved. Be thankful the `body` even works at all, as not all `mailto` handlers support multiple attributes.  I've run into cases before where you can have either a `subject` or a `body` but not both.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use spaces in place of tab since space works. It will look a little ugly but its the end result that matters right?